# Only Keyboard event not mouse events

Tags: c#, scroll, mouseevent, keyboard-events, keydown

I have created event for KeyDown which also triggers the mouse event. I dont want the mouse event. What can i do. Here is my sample code,

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
if (e.KeyCode.ToString().Equals("Up"))
 {
    //...
 }
if (e.KeyCode.ToString().Equals("Down"))
 {
    //...
 }
}
```

This works fine, but whenever i scrool the scrollbar of the mouse it triggers the respective events. What can i do now.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `but whenever i scrool the scrollbar of the mouse` You mean: "*Scroll the mouse wheel*", right?

Comment: Its not very clear which event you want to escape and on what scenario. Please elaborate.

Comment: @Nolonar : Yeah. Scroll the mouse wheel.

Comment: @AseemGautam : I want to escape from mouse scroll wheel event. That is, **if i scroll the mouse wheel it should not trigger the event**.

Comment: @Developer Do you have a program running, that hijacks your mouse wheel and converts it to a key press? Some people use those kinds of programs to: e.g. add gamepad support to old games, or mouse wheel support to apps that don't support the wheel, by simulating a keyboard key press.

Comment: @Nolonar : I don't have such, mine is ordinary c# application. And dont know how this mouse wheel come into action.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help with the mouse issue, but I can suggest an improvement to your code instead: use `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)` instead of `if (e.KeyCode.ToString().Equals("Up"))`. It's much faster, less code, and easier to read (and Intellisense will show you what kinds of keys are recognized).

Comment: Anyway thank you :) Did the modification as you suggest.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a function of the mouse driver...